# HD 6450 drivers not loading in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

Problem:
Sapphire Radeon HD6450 drivers fail to load in Windows 10 (Code 39).
I know it's an old card but it was a budget/purchase for an office PC. The PC is used to draw accident scene plans and is connected to a 40" Sony television.

With the drivers not loading, I'm left with a 1024x768 square in the middle 30% of the screen.

What I've tried:

1. Installed Catalyst 15.7.1 drivers
2. Installed Catalyst 14.x drivers
3. Installed Crimson Beta drivers
4. Installed Adrenalin drivers
5. Installed from Windows Update
6. Removed Registry keys for Upper/Lower filter values

I did clean the old drivers out and rebooted before each installation using the AMD driver removal tool.
I can't seem to get the driver for the HD6450 loading at all in Win 10.

Any help would be appreciated. (Brand new Sapphire HD6450).

Thanks in advance everyone.

Comment: [AMD/ATI driver for Radeon HD 6450 Windows 10 (64bit)](https://www.amdradeondrivers.com/amd-ati-graphics-drivers-Radeon-HD-6450-windows10-64bit.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill - I'd rather the official link - https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-hd/amd-radeon-hd-6000-series/amd-radeon-hd-6350 Daniel - Bad news is these cards were legacied in 2015, so you basically have little to no support for Win10 at all.

Comment: Author already tried the 15.7.1 drivers, while those drivers provided by David are safe (they are signed), they are also available on AMDs website.

Comment: @Ramhound - I'm aware OP already tried 15.7.1 & beta Crimson - after that, it's just plain out of luck. 'Brand new' makes me think someone is still trying to flog off old stock. This is a 2011 GPU. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radeon_HD_6000_series

Comment: Thanks everyone. 
Yeah it's brand new boxed. For some reason I still see a ton of these, as well as GeForce GT710's being sold. 
Must be a weird South African thing.

I'll try Bios update (someone recommended that) and if it doesn't work I will probably just take the hit and get a full upgrade kit. Again, thanks all